# How is moha (मोह) different from kaama (काम)?

Tags: desire, kama

To my best understanding moha (मोह) is enchantment and kaama (काम) is desire. However, I am looking for textual references differentiating the two!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sri Krishna says in Gita about desire - काम and delusion - मोह.

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते।
>
> सङ्गात् संजायते **कामः** कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते।।2.62।।
>
> In the case of a person who dwells on objects, there arises
>   attachment for them. From attachment grows **hankering** (strong desire), from hankering
>   springs anger.
>
> क्रोधाद्भवति **संमोहः** संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः।
>
> स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति।।2.63।।
>
> From anger follows delusion; from **delusion**, failure of memory; from
>   failure of memory, the loss of understanding; from the loss of
>   understanding, he perishes.

So desire - काम is the grand father of the delusion - मोह

Comment: Awesome explanation.